Override X-Frame-Origin SAMEORIGIN
So I have an API endpoint which holds a form. At a different domain, I render this form in an iframe. of course I get CORS errors. Now I want to override the X-Frame-Origin, but it keeps setting it to SAMEORIGIN and my setting. Is there a way to override this?
I am using Laravel 11.
My middleware:
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->headers->remove('X-Frame-Options');
    $response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM *');
    return $response;
}

the console error:
Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('ALLOW-FROM *, SAMEORIGIN'). Falling back to 'deny'.

Thank you!

After looking at the Laravel Forge nginx settings, I found out it's being overwritten here. After changing this, it now works!
